# Count Rows in Dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dataframes. I am trying to count the rows in each dataframe. For the real data, my code is counting just over ten thousand rows for a dataframe that has only has a few rows.

I have tried to reproduce the error using dummy data. Unfortunately, the code works fine with the dummy data!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dataframe
Df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Map
Ma = Df.groupby('D')

# Dictionary of Dataframes
Di = {}
for name, group in Ma:
    Di[str(name)] = group

# Count the Rows in each Dataframe
Li = []
for k in Di:
    Count = Di[k].shape[0]
    Li.append([Count])

# Flatten
Li_1 = []
for sublist in Li:
    for item in sublist:
        Li_1.append(item)

# Histogram
plt.hist(Li_1, bins=10)
plt.xlabel("Rows / Dataframe")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
fig = plt.gcf()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of rows corresponding to each category in `'D'`, you can simply use `.size` when you do your `groupby`:

```
Df.groupby('D').size()
```

`pandas` also allows you to directly plot graphs, so your code can be reduced to:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

Df.groupby('D').size().plot.hist()

plt.xlabel("Rows / Dataframe")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
fig = plt.gcf()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, the data in column `D` is a categorical variable. You can get the count for each category using seaborn `countplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# easy count plot in sns
sns.countplot(x='D',data=df)
plt.xlabel("category")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
```

But if you are looking for distribution plot but not categorical count plot then you can use the folowing part of the code to have distribution plot.

```
# for distribution plot
sns.distplot(df['D'],kde=False,bins=10)
plt.xlabel("Spread")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
```

But if you want distribution plot after group by the elements which does not make any sense to me but you can use the following:

```
# for distribution plot after group by
sns.distplot(df.groupby('D').size() ,kde=False,bins=10)
plt.xlabel("Spread")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
```